$f(f^{-1}(B')) = B'$ in category theory
I need to prove:
Let $C$ be a category with equalizer , coequalizer, kernels, cokernels, normal and conormal. Let $f : A \to B$ be an epimorphism and $u : B' \to B$ a subobject of $B$. Then $f(f^{-1}(B')) = B'$.
My attempt:

\begin{array}{ccc}
 &        & B' \\
            & & \downarrow u \\
A & \xrightarrow{f} & B
\end{array}
Since $\mathcal{C}$ is normal and has kernels, it has inverse images. Let us consider:

\begin{array}{ccc}
f^{-1}(B') & \to & B' \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow u \\
A & \xrightarrow{f} & B
\end{array}
Then $f^{-1}(B') \cong$ subobject of $A$ and is the largest object mapped to $B$ via $f$.
Since $\mathcal{C}$ is conormal, $f: A \to B$ being an epimorphism is the cokernel of some morphism $f': A' \to A$. Therefore, we have the sequence
$A' \xrightarrow{f'} A \xrightarrow{f} B \to B$
Then we have that $f f'$ is the kernel of $g$, since $f f' = 0$, hence $g f f' = 0$.
I don't know how can I follow, why I need equalizers and coequalizer? Any hint?

I assume your category is preadditive? Or is it even abelian?

@MartinBrandenburg my teacher only said me that I need to prove the category is exact

It seems to me that you would need to assume that cokernels or regular epimorphisms are pullback-stable to get your results, is that what you mean by $\mathcal{C}$ being normal?

Yes, that's normal.
